# Inaccessibility when friend struct inherits class

Tags: c++, inheritance, visual-c++, friend, access-control

I have a situation where I want to hide a base class and limit the classes that can inherit from it:

```
namespace _detail {
    class Private abstract final {
        struct Base abstract {
        protected:
            Base() {}
        };

        friend struct ::A;
        friend struct ::B;
        friend struct ::C;
    };
}

struct A : _detail::Private::Base {}; //error
struct B : _detail::Private::Base {}; //error
struct C : _detail::Private::Base {}; //error
```

The compiler tells me that `_detail::Private::Base` is inaccessible to `A`, `B` and `C` even though they are friends with `Private`.  I've used this sort of pattern before without an issue, and can't really see what's different here compared to the other times I've used it.  What am I not seeing?

Comment: `friend struct A;` declares a struct in namespace `_detail` as friend.

Comment: @sftrabbit It works, so why not?

Comment: @DyP sorry forgot to put the :: operator

Comment: @sftrabbit **visual** C++, see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0z6b513.aspx)

Comment: Now you need forward-declarations. But then it should work (for Standard C++, ignoring `abstract`).

Comment: @DyP Oh, okay.  That worked.  I guess I just always forward-declared everything when I used this sort of pattern.

Comment: That's a good idea, as `friend` can declare new things in the surrounding namespace. If you don't want that, use forward-declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ language does not allow you to use *qualified* names (like `::A`) in friend declarations, unless these qualified names refer to *previously declared entities*. Actually, this rule is applied virtualy everywhere, not only in friend declarations: qualified names have to refer to previously declared entities.

In your case you used qualified name `::A` in friend declaration `friend struct ::A`. For that to work, `struct A` from global namespace has to be known to the compiler beforehand. In your case `A` is not declared at that point, which makes `friend struct ::A` declaration ill-formed. It should not even compile by formal rules of the language.

If your compiler accepts this, you have to consult your compiler documentatuion to figure out what it means. I suspect that `friend struct ::A` for unknown `::A` is interpreted as equivalent to `friend struct A`, i.e. it declares `_detail::A` as friend.

If you make a forward declaration `struct A;` before declaring namespace `_detail`, it might make it work as intended.